# How to find column names from table with specific confitions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to find column name where column value is 1 AND where userid=3
for example i have a table

question

```
 quesitonid   userid      answer1 answer2 answer3 
  1            1          0         1        0   
  2            2          1         0        0
  3            3          0         0       1
```

the result will be produced as

```
  question1   userid   answer3
     3           3         1
```

How can i do that with sql? i tried a lot but didn't get success, if any one can help, million of thanks in advance for him....

This is my sql query

```
SELECT * from questions Q WHERE  Q.userid=1 AND (Q.answer1=1 OR Q.answer2=1 OR Q.answer3=1)
```

Comment: Why do you want it with SQL?

Comment: basically i want to optimize query, i dont wont to do that throug code..

Comment: Your normalization is wrong. Never do these things this way. The question has to be separated from the possible answers.

Comment: i accept my normailization is wrong, but database provided to me is from client, i am bounded. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
,CASE
    WHEN ( answer1 =1)   THEN 'answer1'
    WHEN ( answer2 =1)  THEN 'answer2'
    WHEN ( answer3 =1)   THEN ' answer3'
    ELSE 'nobody'
END
AS selected_answer
FROM Q
WHERE  Q.userid=1 AND (Q.answer1=1 OR Q.answer2=1 OR Q.answer3=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to divide your tables into 4 like these:

**User: id - name**

**Question: id - text**

**Answer: id - fk_question - text**

**User_answers: id - fk_user - fk_question - fk_answer**

my export for you:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_question` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `answer` (`id`, `fk_question`, `text`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'it is 3'),
(2, 1, 'it is 2'),
(3, 1, 'it is 5');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `question` (`id`, `text`) VALUES
(1, 'what is 1 + 1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'pipo'),
(2, 'kees'),
(3, 'jan'),
(4, 'hessel'),
(5, 'geke'),
(6, 'daan'),
(7, 'ray'),
(8, 'jelle'),
(9, 'klaas'),
(10, 'berent');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_question` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_answer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `users_answers` (`id`, `fk_user`, `fk_question`, `fk_answer`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 2),
(2, 4, 1, 3);
```

Then it is very easy you don't need to look which column name is set to 1 you just get the data. This way there can be more than 3 answer. Infact now its variable:

```
SELECT q.`id` , u.`id` , a.`id`
FROM  `users_answers` ua
INNER JOIN  `users` u ON ua.`fk_user` = u.`id`
INNER JOIN  `question` q ON ua.`fk_question` = q.`id`
INNER JOIN  `answer` a ON ua.`fk_answer` = a.`id`
WHERE u.`id` =2
```

Will return

```
question    user    answer

1             2        2
```

but I would directly use this:

```
SELECT q.`text` AS  `question` , u.`name` AS  `user` , a.`text` AS  `answer` 
FROM  `users_answers` ua
INNER JOIN  `users` u ON ua.`fk_user` = u.`id` 
INNER JOIN  `question` q ON ua.`fk_question` = q.`id` 
INNER JOIN  `answer` a ON ua.`fk_answer` = a.`id` 
WHERE u.`id` =2
AND q.`id` =1
```

It returns:

```
question        user    answer
what is 1 + 1   kees    it is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring back only certain columns based on whether they contain a value or not that will not be possible in SQL.  The only way you will be able to achieve this is using PIVOT, if not you will have to bring back all the columns established in your select statement.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to do what you want is to get the data with the query you posted above and the iterate over the result(s) and fetch the wanted columns on the client side (in php, in your case).

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM question WHERE userid = 1 AND (answer1 =1 || answer2 =1 || answer3=1)

This display you the full table with respective matches . Further you can fetch the records which ever you want individually and go with the further actions in you program .